# False Positive in Face Recognition

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, face-recognition

I am involved in a project concerning the face recognition of images, of these images once I have used my CNN I must personally indicate the number of True Positive, True Negative, False Positive and False Negative present.

From what I know the **True Positive** indicates the number of faces correctly identified, so if I have 3 faces in an image and the machine identifies them then I have 3 True Positives, the **True Negative** indicates that the machine has not identified faces where faces do not are, the **False Positive** indicates errors of the machine that identifies faces where there are none and the **False Negative** indicates that the machine does not identify faces that are in fact there.

Unfortunately I didn't understand the concept of True Negative very well, how can I understand how many cases of True negative I have in a processing?
For example, if in a photo I have 3 faces and the machine identifies 3 of them then I will have 3 True Positive, 0 False Negative, 0 False Positive but how many True Negative will I have?

Answer (score 0):

When you are talking about an image with 3 faces, that means your method (or any other face recognition method) probably runs series of testing on different section (sub-images) of the original image and find faces. In this cases, there are lots of frames where no face exists and your method did correctly and didn't find any face (equivalent to True Negative). You should count these tests.

In order to do that, you can reduce you problem to another problem which returns True/False to the question "Whether a face exists in this image or not?". Then you have a large image, you can break it into smaller images (or using a sliding-window that moves on the image). Then your measurements will be like:

**True Positive**: Number of frames where a face existed and your method returned True.

**True Negative**: Number of frames where no face existed and your method returned False.

**False Positive**: Number of frames where no face existed but your method returned True.

**False Negative**: Number of frames where a face existed but your method returned False.

Comment: I'm using YOLOv3 for face recognition, I understood your speech and I agree, but if I wanted to reduce the problem to the way I described before, that is, given an image with three faces inside, if the machine identifies all three the faces how many True Negative cases do I have?

Comment: Well the shortest answer is many or unknown. You can break your images into smaller images all having size equal to the size of the convolution filters in the first layer of YOLOv3 and say all of them are True Negatives or something like that.